# how to change the reCaptcha's style like stackoverflow and facebook 

Tags: javascript, django, coding-style, recaptcha

i dont like the red background ,and want to change the button to other place .

Is there a easy way to do this ?

Should i have to change the css style one by one ?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read the documentation at http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'theme_name'
 };
 </script>
```

it has four ready-made themes (*red, white, blackglass, clean*), and you can also create your own.

Answer (score 3):

You may need [this](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization?csw=1)

If you have a more specific question, post it. Yours looks generic, so I redirected you to the most generic article about it.